# ScrollView превращает ListView в одну строку

Tags: android, listview

В меню игры 2 списка `ListView`. Из них нужно выбрать модель и режим игры. Я помещаю весь экран внутри `ScrollView`, чтобы при изменении ориентации строки списка не вышли из экрана. Но `ScrollView` превращает оба `ListView` в строки. Как исправить?

В xml коде экрана все параметры-`match_parent`, кроме корневого layout и 2-х текстов.

```
<RelativeLayout ...(корневой)>
<ScrollView>
    <HorizontalScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout> 
            <TextView ... />
            <ListView ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <ListView ... />
            <Button ... />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код списков:

```
String[] list = {"Animals", "Dishes", "Figures", "Flags", "Fruits", "Football players", "Musical instruments", "Numbers", "Tools", "Transportation"};
String[] list2 = {"Small", "Medium", "Big"};
ListView listView, listView2;
TextView textView, textView2;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylistlayout, list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylistlayout, list2);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView0);
    listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    listView2.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

А вот картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это потому, что вкладывать скролящийся view в скролящийся view нелльзя. используйте хедер и футер у листвью

Answer (score 4):

Вкладывать ListView в ScrollView не лучшая идея. Т.к. ListView сам умеет скролить и возможны проблемы. В Вашем случае проще организовать необходимый выбор при помощи диалогов

Comment: Т.е. на одном экране желательно не иметь больше одного списка?

Comment: да,каждый диалог представляется отдельным экраном, либо перепроектировать существующий